# C# Console App - Modify Permissions

Tags: c#, .net, file-permissions, auto-update

I have a Windows Service that checks for a web API for updates and when it finds them it downloads them, unzips them to a temp directory and then launches a separate console app that stops the Windows Service and copies all the files overwriting the old ones.

The issue is that the updater doesn't have permission to overwrite the files in that directory, `c:\Program Files (x86)\myApp`, unless it runs as Administrator. I have tried to add the `.manifest` file with `requestedExecutionLevel` `requireAdministrator` to the update script, but that doesn't do anything. The Service that launches it is running as LocalSystem, so I tried `asInvoker`, but that didn't work either.

The interesting thing is that part of the script has a StreamWriter to log events. I am able to create a file in the directory, but then don't have rights to edit that file.

I originally had the updater being launched from a WPF section of the app rather than the Windows Service, but then realized that if no user was logged in, then it wouldn't update. Is there a way around this? Here is the relevant snippet I am working with:

```
// Load the update path
Console.WriteLine("Loading update path from UpdatePath.txt"); 
string[] zipDir = File.ReadAllLines("UpdatePath.txt");
Console.WriteLine("Loading update from: " + zipDir);

// Copy all the updated files to the current directory (this will include the renamed service.exe)
Console.WriteLine("Copying zip contents to current directory ( " + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + " )");
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(zipDir[0], "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach (string f in files)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(f);
    if(fileName != "Configuration.ini") {
        Console.WriteLine("Copying " + f + " =>" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +"//" + fileName);
        File.Copy(f, fileName, true);  //Breaks right here
    }
}
```

The `Console.WriteLine()` used to write to a file, but it broke there too so I changed it.

Comment: Good. Upgrading is definitely something that *requires* permission from the end user. Not necessarily administrator priviledges but still, this is a *good* thing. Trying to install something without the user or the administrator noticing or consenting is not a good idea

Comment: All these are solved issues anyway - you could use [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel), a well-known autoupdater. It was featured [in this DotNetRocks](https://www.dotnetrocks.com/?show=1535) episode recently. Windows itself can deploy MSI installers to any machine in a domain whether a user is logged on or not through Group Policies, Powershell DSC etc.

Comment: In any case Windows prevents modification of `Program Files` since the Windows 95 days to prevent ill-behaved applications from breaking the system or other applications. User-specific data, documents are supposed to be stored in the user's profile or `My Documents`. This is also well-known. Application data is supposed to be stored in `ProgramData`. Chocolatey for example stores all packages in the `ProgramData\chocolatey` folder

Comment: Thanks guys. Panagiotis, the app is installed on a headless server which to get access to the office often has to contact an IT company to service. As a new service, we are making semi frequent changes to the app and can't involve the end user every time. I am looking into Squirrel, which looks nice.

Comment: that doesn't matter. Continuous Deployment or Powershell DSC work without requiring user interaction to deploy to multiple servers. The problem is the inappropriate installer, not permissions or users

Comment: Chocolatey doesn't require user interaction either - in the simplest case you can just connect to a remote server with `Enter-PSSession thatServerName` and run `choco upgrade mypackage`. This will uninstall the previous version and install a new one. You can use even a local folder as package source. Powershell DSC takes this one step farther - you can define what each server should contain/look like in a DSC file and Powershell will go and create the appropriate scripts to install packages, set up shares, IPs etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following code to grant access to the Folder I created.

Need to use the namespace "**using System.Security.AccessControl;**"

```
 private static void CreateSomeFolder()
 {
        try
        {
            //Create some folder and grant full permissions
            var someFolder = "SomeDataFolderPath";
            if (Directory.Exists(someFolder)) return;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(someFolder);
            GrantAccess(someFolder);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Folder Creation Error - ", ex);
        }
 }

private static bool GrantAccess(string fullPath)
{
   var dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
   var dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
   dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
   dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
   return true; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kishore, this combined with the NSIS Access-Control plugin solved the problem. http://nsis.sourceforge.net/AccessControl_plug-in